# In AWS s3, suddenly cannot see any public bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In AWS s3 web console, suddenly I cannot see any public bucket.

[image]

Comment: The search box (below where it says "General purpose buckets") appears to contain `we` -- if you delete that text, your buckets should appear. Please note that it will only list buckets in _your_ AWS Account, and it will list the buckets whether or not they are "public".

Comment: I know if i delete "we" it shows my own buckets.  I want to find global public buckets

Comment: The S3 management console **only** shows buckets in your **own** AWS Account. It is not possible to list "global public buckets" in the console. However if you know the name of such a bucket you can access it via API calls and the AWS CLI (eg `aws s3 ls s3://nyc-tlc/`).

Comment: You said "suddenly I cannot see any public bucket". What were you able to see previously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to list "global public buckets" in the S3 management console.

However, if you know the name of a bucket, you can **cheat** a little bit to access the bucket in the console:

- In the S3 management console, click on a bucket in your AWS Account
- Then, **change the URL** in your web browser to use the 'public' bucket name instead of your own bucket name

In this example, the bucket name was changed to `nyc-tlc`, which is from [New York City Taxi and Limousine Commission (TLC) Trip Record Data - Registry of Open Data on AWS](https://registry.opendata.aws/nyc-tlc-trip-records-pds/):

```
https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/nyc-tlc?region=us-east-1&bucketType=general&tab=objects
```

You can then use the S3 management console to navigate the bucket and download objects **if the owner of the bucket has made the objects public**.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly remove `we` from the search box. You would be able to see all